# Javascript - Passing value to function from multiple divs with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have a small question about a script I found and edited. 
Originally, the script was getting the value from a single input with a specific id. 
What I need is to send a specific value from multiple divs (those divs are dynamically created from a variable with multiple objects - function colors()). 
But since it is an itteration, it cannot generate multiple id's for the div in question (actually it could by generating the name of each object as div id - but then the function wouldn't know where to get the values from, am I wrong here?).
To be more clear, this is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <div><img src="mug.png" id="mug" onload="getPixels(this)" /></div>
    <input type="text" id="color" value="#6491ee" />
    <input type="button" value="change color" onclick="changeColor()">
    <div id="colorsContainer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var colors = [
            { nume: "Orange", hex: "#ff6439" },
            { nume: "Blue", hex: "#488dff" }
            ];
function colors(){
for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("colorsContainer");
    theDiv.innerHTML += "<div id='color1' value="+colors[i].hex+" onclick='changeColor()'>"+colors[i].name+"</div><div style='background-color: "+colors[i].hex+"; width: 120px; height:120px;'></div><br>";
}
}
window.onload = colors;
        var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var originalPixels = null;
        var currentPixels = null;

        function HexToRGB(Hex)
        {
            var Long = parseInt(Hex.replace(/^#/, ""), 16);
            return {
                R: (Long >>> 16) & 0xff,
                G: (Long >>> 8) & 0xff,
                B: Long & 0xff
            };
        }

        function changeColor()
        {
            if(!originalPixels) return;
            var newColor = HexToRGB(document.getElementById("color").value);

            for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
            {
                if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0)
                {
                    currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
                    currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
                    currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
                }
            }

            ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
            mug.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }

        function getPixels(img)
        {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            originalPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            currentPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

            img.onload = null;
        }
    </script>
```

So again, how can I modify the script in order to send the value to the changeColor() function of each generated div in the colors() function whenever one of those divs are clicked?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Having the same `id` for many elements isn't valid. Use `class` and use a `for` loop to go through each one in the `changeColor()` function.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek , I understand the class part but I don't understand the other part of your suggestion.

Comment: Isn't your code acting weird. You define colors twice. Once as an array and directly after it as a function. the array should be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One single approach would be declaring a formal parameter in the changeColor function. You have two alternatives:

- Either to pass directly the color value:

  ```html
  function changeColor(newColor) {...}
  function colors()
  {
      ...
      theDiv.innerHTML += "<div value='"+colors[i].hex+"' onclick='changeColor(\""+colors[i].hex+"\")'>...</div><br>";
      ...
  }
  ```
- Either to pass the div's ID (and, of corse, each div must have a *unique* ID).

  ```html
  function changeColor(id)
  {
      var newColor = HexToRGB(document.getElementById(id).value);
      ...
  }

  function colors()
  {
      ...
      for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
      {
          var id="color"+i;
          theDiv.innerHTML += "<div id='"+id+"' value='"+colors[i].hex+"' onclick='changeColor(\""+id+"\")'>...</div><br>";
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: after trying your second suggestion I get the following error in debug: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined on line 28 -> var Long = parseInt(Hex.replace(/^#/, ""), 16);

Comment: Your first solution worked with a little bit of tweak, I have changed the var newColor line to var newColor = HexToRGB(newColor). Thank you very much for your time and guiding!